# Use PhoneGap and also show iAd

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova, iad

I am trying to create an iPad app using PhoneGap..

Now while I know, I can just create .html pages and show them using PhoneGap as native app. My question is I also wanted to show iAd below all the html pages in the app.

How do I add the iAd given that I am using PhoneGap? Any example would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the very good tutorial here :

http://www.zeletron.com.br/2010/07/adding-iad-in-phonegap-apps.html

Regards

Comment: I tried that, but am getting some error........“_CGRectZero”, referenced from:
_CGRectZero$non_lazy_ptr in MainViewController.o
(maybe you meant: _CGRectZero$non_lazy_ptr)
“_CGRectOffset”, referenced from:
-[MainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] in MainViewController.o
-[MainViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:] in MainViewController.o
-[MainViewController viewDidLoad] in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found

Comment: Basically the error is "Symbol not found for architecture i386"

Comment: I do not know if I need to change the default settings of the PhoneGap project now that I have added iAd...which i am not sure works on which IOS versions + ?

Comment: Which version of phonegap are you using ?

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had luck using the phonegap AdPlugin at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/AdPlugin/

The sample app is a good guide and I also referred to the following:
http://www.amershamequestrian.com/public/docs/How%20to%20get%20iAds%20Working%20in%20PhoneGap.pdf